Connecting Hukseflux SR05-D2A2 pyranometer thermal sensor
I have this Hukseflux SR05-D2A2 pyranometer thermal sensor, that support Modbus communication through a TTL interface and I would like to connect it to an Arduino, but I have some doubts about the wiring, so I’m asking for your help.
My main concern is related to the TTL communication protocol. I’ve used some RS485-type sensors before that required an additional RS485-to-TTL converter to connect to a microcontroller. In this case, since the protocol is already TTL, do I just need to connect the RX and TX of the pyranometer directly to microcontroler? Or do I still need an additional RS232 converter?
Another question I have is about the wires (pg 37):

My interpretation is to connect the power supply: positive to Brown and negative to Blue. Then, connect Black, White, and Grey to the microcontroller's GND, TX, and RX, respectively. Does this seem correct? And what about the Yellow (shield)? Should I connect it to the microcontroller's GND as well?
In the datasheet, there is this warning: "If the TTL device to which SR05-D2A2 is connected requires external power, this power must be drawn from a separate power supply with a floating potential with respect to the power supply used by SR05-D2A2."
So, I need two different power supplies—one for the pyranometer and another for the Arduino? Is that correct?
Thanks

What are the voltage levels.?

The manual suggests you can use a simple USB-TTL converter, or convert it to RS-232 and use an RS-232 port on your computer.
You would likely prefer the latter if you have a long distance between the computer and the sensor. If it's something short, like 1m indoors, in a benign electrical environment, then there is probably no need.

So for your MCU it looks like you need two different supplies, at least one of which must be isolated from earth. And probably the voltage levels are 5V so 3.3V Arduinos, Raspberry Pi, Beagle Bone, etc. are out unless you add a voltage converter.
